# React Framer Motion. Simple drag with overriding position when button pressed

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I want to have drag with `dragConstraints`. And it works fine. But also I want to change draggable block position from outside. For example if I click button, then block should automatically smoothly go to defined position. I found that there is `useSpring` hook, but if I use it in `style` prop then normal drag is broken. (`style={{ x: spring}}`)

I've created small demo on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-drag-with-constraints-forked-qd5n0x?file=/src/Example.tsx). Maybe someone could help me or give ideas, how it should be implemented?

This is going to be used in one page navigation. Navigation is long and some links are outside of viewport. I want to scroll `motion.div` automatically to active link. And user should able to scroll (drag) manually (`.drag-area` will be with `overflow: hidden`).

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useRef } from "react";
import { motion, useMotionValue, useSpring } from "framer-motion";

export const Example = () => {
  const constraintsRef = useRef(null);

  const x = useMotionValue(0);
  const spring = useSpring(x);
  const onClick = () => {
    // spring.set(-200);
    x.set(-200);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <motion.div className="drag-area" ref={constraintsRef}>
        <motion.div
          className="drag-block"
          drag="x"
          dragConstraints={constraintsRef}
          style={{ x }}
        />
      </motion.div>

      <button className="button" onClick={onClick}>
        Set -200px
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```